# My site is inaccessible from different locations on-and-off. What's happening?

Tags: networking, web-server, ddos

On-and-off for the last few days, my sites (www.)aderet.org  and to a lesser extent  (www.)saveadullam.org have been down from (two different networks in) Israel. Over a period of minutes or seconds, they can go up and down.

A test at downforeveryoneorjustme.com generally shows that they are up. Access from Tor, which comes through other locations worldwide, is generally OK. Monitor.us sometimes sends alerts that the sites are down (with monitors in the US, Europe, and Asia), but not always (See image).

They are small, static, low-traffic sites at Freehostia. I don't think that the fact that it's free hosting is the problem, given the strange behavior.

I thought of DDoS attacks, but there is no sign of them. Statcounter shows no abnormal activity. Server stats show 14.5 MB transferred in the last day.

Any idea about what is going on?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I heard from various sorts that Google was inaccessible from parts of the Middle East, South America and some Southeast Asia countries yesterday. Has connectivity been restored for your users? I would shrug it off as DNS issues but could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but this wasn't google -- it was my own sites, aderet.org and to a lesser extent saveadullam.org